# localized version of MFC strings

Tags: string, mfc, localization

I try to localize a DLL which is linked with MFC statically. I notice there are a lot of strings that are from MFC, like this:

61440   Open

61441   Save As

I think there should be already localized version, for example, German version for these standard strings so I do not need to translate them again. How to find and get them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You find the German resources for VS-2010 here

\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\l.deu